# JavaScript Accordion: Why does it squash on smaller screens?

Tags: javascript, accordion

I don't want to use an entire library (jQuery UI) just to achieve this simple effect. The code I am using works to a certain degree, but it squashes when the browser is resized to below 1000px.

The result is on my FAQ page here: https://www.unidrones.co.za/VRentals/faq (you'll notice the answer starts to hide behind the next accordion as the screen gets smaller)

I tried replacing the "px" with "em" but that doesn't work. What should I do to make it work like a normal accordion for all screen sizes?

```
<ul id="accordion">
<li><p>Question...</p></li>
<li><p>Answer...</p></li>
<li><p>Question...</p></li>
<li><p>Answer...</p></li>
</ul>

<script>
$("#accordion li:even").addClass("accordion");
$("#accordion li:odd").addClass("panel");
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("activeAccordion");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

P.S. I used the jQueryUI component here https://www.fishgelatine.co.za/recipes and that's the way I want my vanilla JS accordion to work.

Comment: what do you mean by squash? Its working fine on my machine. ANy specific browser?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma you'll notice the text from the answers start to hide behind the questions when the screen gets smaller. I'm using Chrome but I tested it on Firefox, Opera and IE.

Comment: Did my ans solve your issue @JDoe ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your max-height on panel div is the issue. Please try calculating height of all opened accordians after window resize. That should solve your issue. You just need to run the code that calculates height in your above code in the window.resize function for all the opened accordians.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", recalculate(function(e){
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        var panel = acc[i].nextElementSibling;  
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
});
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("activeAccordion");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;  
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;  
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }     
  });
}
```

Or you can do the following too.

I think you should `remove this part` of your js

```
if (panel.style.maxHeight){
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

Instead write this

```
if (panel.style.display === "block"){
  panel.style.display = null;
} else {
    panel.style.display = "block";
}
```

And Add this CSS

```
#faq .panel {
    display: none;
}
```

But its downside is that your animation effects won't show so you can also do this.

Or you can also do this

Change your max-height code like this

```
if (panel.style.maxHeight === "inherit"){
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = "inherit";
}
```

Comment: Removing this part of the code will deactivate the accordion entirely... I took your tip that the max-height is causing the problem and tried playing around with other options to no avail. Currently the accordion works perfectly if you click it and keep the browser at that size. Resizing the browser messes it up, and I have no idea why.

Comment: You made this accordian yourself? Why not use some framework’s accordian? likr bootstrap’s accordian works very well

Comment: I am using vanilla JS because I don't want to use any framework or library for this project. I used jQueryUI's component here https://www.fishgelatine.co.za/recipes and that works wonderfully, only I would like to replicate it in pure JavaScript.

Comment: thats because you are calculating height of opened accordian according to that window width when it was opend. You need to update the height of opened accordians on window resize.

Comment: please try calculating height of all opened accordians after window resize. That should solve your issue. You just need to run the code that I told you to comment out in the window.resize function for all the opened accordians.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp You can try this accordian. its purely js and css. I hope it helps you figure out your issue as well

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the window.resize and let you know the outcome

Comment: No leave the resize. I updated the answer please check that. Its a better approach

Comment: Actually I just completed the test and the window.resize worked perfectly! I had to place the eventListener inside the else statement and repeat the calculation inside the event. Check the website to ee how it works. I'll mark this question as solved if you write that logic (setting a window.resize event) into your question :)

Comment: Updated the answer and also tried to write your resize code properly. May be that some braces are not closed properly, but basically it shows the logic that I have explained. Please try it and  let me know if it worked well for you, Thanks